# How to open URL in new IE tab using VBS?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, vbscript

I want to open a number of URLs using VBS and need the login credentials to be entered in directly. PFB my code:

```
    WScript.Quit Main

    Function Main
      Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      IE.Visible = True
      IE.Navigate "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https://www.google.co.in/%3Fgws_rd%3Dcr%26ei%3DoSiwUqWmO8LvkQXGhIGoBg"
      Wait IE
      With IE.Document
        .get

ElementByID("Email").value = "xyz@gmail.com"
    .getElementByID("Passwd").value = "123"
  End With
  IE.Navigate "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https://www.google.co.in/%3Fgws_rd%3Dcr%26ei%3DoSiwUqWmO8LvkQXGhIGoBg"
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("Email").value = "abc@gmail.com"
    .getElementByID("Passwd").value = "12345"
  End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
End Sub

Sub IE_OnQuit
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
  WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

I would be grateful if somebody could clarify the following doubts for me:

1. How do i ensure that this links open in the same window but different tabs?
2. I tried a couple of things but could not write a code such that the login button is clicked via the code. Is there a way to do it?
3. I read in a few places that VBS doesn't work with Chrome. But frankly, IE is not very convenient to use. So is there some way by which i could achieve similar results in Chrome?

Trying out VBS for the first time so I might come across as a little naive!
Please bear!
:)

Thanks in advance!
:)